# Rails/Formtastic Newbie: Setting display field for referenced "select" box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

New `formtastic` user here.

I have a relationship `user has_many clients`

In `formtastic`, if I do something such as

```
f.input :employer
```

it returns a select box of all employer object references. I'd like to display (last name, first name) instead. I'm sure this is very simple, but I can't figure out exactly how to do it.. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

`f.input :employers, :as => :select, :collection => Employer.find(:all, :order => "last_name ASC")`

or

`f.input :employers, :as => :select, :collection => Employer.collect {|e| [e.last_name, e.id] }`

Answer (score 6):

These didnt work for me, however, this did:

```
<%= f.input :user, :label => "Author", :label_method => :username %>
```

Also a little cleaner ^^

Or, you can set the display method once and for all on the model itself:

*(In employer.rb)*

```
def to_label
  email
end
```